# Problen with Object not appearing in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

i don´t know what`s happenig why isn´t rendering but in the last proyect everything was fine. Hope someone can help.
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The grey Background with the grid means, there is no Image to preview. You did not actually start a Render. You can start a Render in the Header via `Render` > `Render Image` or by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd>.

You probably used `View Render` or <kbd>F11</kbd>, wich displays the last Render (in this Case None).